# WooCommerce Booking Display Block Count Cost Field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

How do I display the Block Count Range Type?

It is calculating correctly but I want to show this on the front end (single-product.php) so customers know what additional costs are included.

e.g. insurance fee per day, additional fee, service fee per day, etc.

[image: WooCommerce Bookable Product Additional Costs]

There may be a better way to handle dynamic additional cost fields, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to display the block cost from the last row on my product archive page if it is a bookable product.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theme_variation_price', 10, 2);
function theme_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $product_pricing = get_post_meta( $product->get_id() , '_wc_booking_pricing', false);

    $cost = $price;
    foreach ($product_pricing as $pricing) {
        if (is_array($pricing)){
            foreach ($pricing as $price) {
                $cost = $price['cost'];
            }
        }
    }

    if( $product->is_type( 'booking' ) ) {
        return $cost;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

`$product_pricing` is an array:

```
Array
(
    [type] => days
    [cost] => 100
    [modifier] => equals
    [base_cost] => 
    [base_modifier] => 
    [from] => 6
    [to] => 7
)
```

So if you want the type, just change `$price['cost']` with `$price['type']`.